# Delete item from List in Redis within .NET

Tags: list, redis

I was wondering if anyone has used Redis in .NET application. I am trying to delete an item from a list using the following code:

```
_redis.Lists["urn:notification"].Remove(entity);
```

It doesn't seem to do anything to the item in the list.

I was able to store and update item in the list.

If anyone can shed some light on this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The Lists data structure can only be "popped" to get an item off the top of the list.

You may be thinking of Sets, where you can remove any item at will if you know the corresponding key for the set.

Answer (score 0):

From http://redis.io/commands/lrem:

```
use LREM(key, count, value)

redis> RPUSH mylist "hello"
(integer) 1
redis> RPUSH mylist "hello"
(integer) 2
redis> RPUSH mylist "foo"
(integer) 3
redis> RPUSH mylist "hello"
(integer) 4
redis> LREM mylist -2 "hello"
(integer) 2
redis> LRANGE mylist 0 -1
1) "hello"
2) "foo"
redis>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RemoveValue` method from `IRedisList<T>` instead

```
_redis.Lists["urn:notification"].RemoveValue(entity);
```